# Xcode crash when adding images to images.xcassets

Tags: xcode, ios7, crash, png, provisioning-profile

I just set up a provisioning profile to test my app on my iphone device.  Since I did, I now cannot add anymore images to the images.xcassets folder.  It causes xCode to crash.  I tried refreshing my signing identities and provisioning profiles in Xcode, as one thread recommended, but it did not work.  It's clear to me that it is somehow related to the provisioning profile though.  Anyone?

Comment: Xcode shouldn't crash at all.  If you can reproduce it 100% of the time, send the reproduction steps and a crash log to Apple via http://bugreporter.apple.com